# Как создать дерево из JSON без рекурсии и без библиотек

Tags: javascript, json

Получаю JSON строку, превращаю эту строку в массив и создаю дерево (список `ul-li`).
Делаю это с помощью рекурсии.
Как это можно реализовать с помощью цикла на `JavaScript`?

Для этого написал такую функцию:

```
function createJsonTree(objData) {

    if (isChild(objData)) return;

    var ul = createElem('ul');

    for (var i = 0, length = objData.length; i < length; i++) {
        if (i in objData) {

            var li = createElem('li');
            if (objData[i].dropmenu) {
                var toggleDiv = createElem('div');

                li.appendChild(toggleDiv);
            }

            li.innerHTML = objData[i].NAMEGROUP;
            li.id = objData[i].GROUPID;

            var childUl = createJsonTree(objData[i].dropmenu);
            if (childUl) li.appendChild(childUl);

            ul.appendChild(li);

        }
    }
    return ul;
}
```

Спасибо всем за помощь!

Comment: 1) Что в полученном JSON? 2) Приведите псевдокод, который нужно получить.

Comment: @shatal Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий ответом.

Comment: Спасибо всем за помощь!
Все же попробую реализовать без рекурсии...